# Getting a strange unexpected token with creating a file upload in React.js

Tags: javascript, file-upload, reactjs

I am using React as framework to create input for a project. Input is a name, photo and an optional comment. The name and comment I got working, but the photo (being a file) gives me some trouble.

I am using [this](https://medium.com/@greggawatt/simple-file-uploads-in-react-js-backbone-js-and-rails-7a4ab43c7e27#.x9leoowkx) as a method for uploading. (I know that the quality of the photo must be very low to use base64 for it, but that is not a problem for this project.)

However, when I used this code, my browser threw an Unexpected token error in the console, at a location where there was just a tab. I have located the error to this piece of code (by commenting out different pieces).

```
reader.onload = function(output){
      fileUpload.set({
         file: output.target.result
      });
      $.when(fileUpload.save())
        .done(function(){
        this.setState({
          uploaded: true
        });
      }.bind(this));
    }.bind(this));
```

I just can't see what is wrong with it and why it is throwing that error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your parens may be mismatched. Here's the same code with additional formatting:

```
reader.onload = function(output) {

  fileUpload.set({ file: output.target.result });

  $.when(fileUpload.save())
  .done(
    function() {
      this.setState({ uploaded: true });
    }.bind(this)
  );

}.bind(this)
); // extra
```

The last line has an additional `)` that does not have a matching `(` at the start of the expression.